# Query to obtain the Supervisor from Table2 while displaying information from Table1

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, Table1 and Table2.

Table1 has the Employee Number and other attributes e.g. FirstName and LastName.
Table2 has the Employee Number and a corresponding Supervisor Employee Number.

All names, including the supervisor's is on Table1.

I want to write a query to add the Supervisor Name to the list of items I am querying from Table1.  What is the best way to do this?

A sample of my SQL is as follow:

```
Select EmplNo, LastName, FirstName
      From Table1
      Where LastName Between "Apple" and "Orange"
      Order by LastName
```

Table1 data example:

```
EmplNo LastName FirstName Salary
12345  Apple    John      $50,000
23456  Brown    Mary      $51,000
34567  Golden   Frank     $72,000
89012  Holland  Maggie   $100,000
```

Table2 data example:

```
EmplNo SupNo
12345  34567
23456  34567
34567  89012
```

The current Result:

```
EmplNo LastName FirstName Salary
12345  Apple    John      $50,000
12345  Apple    John      $50,000
23456  Brown    Mary      $51,000
34567  Golden   Frank     $72,000
```

What I need to see is:

```
EmplNo LastName FirstName Supervisor
12345  Apple    John      Frank Golden
23456  Brown    Mary      Frank Golden
34567  Golden   Frank     Maggie Holland
89012  Holland  Maggie    NULL
```

Please let me know the best way to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join from Table1 to Table2 to find each employee's supervisor. Then you need to join to Table1 again to get the name of the supervisor.

```
select emp.EmplNo
     , emp.LastName
     , emp.FirstName
     , sup.FirstName + ' ' + sup.LastName as Supervisor
from Table1 emp
left join Table2 t2 on emp.EmplNo = t2.EmplNo
left join Table1 sup on t2.SupNo = sup.EmplNo
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and for explaining your answer.  This query worked perfectly.  Of course my query was much bigger with many other tables joined.  But when I added a sample of your code, it work perfectly.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a couple of `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT E.EmplNo
       E.LastName
       E.FirstName
       NULLIF(CONCAT(S.FirstName, ' ', S.LastName),' ') AS Supervisor
FROM dbo.Employee E
     LEFT JOIN dbo.EmployeeSupervisors ES ON E.EmplNo = ES.EmplNo
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Employee S ON ES.SupNo = E.EmplNo;
```

Comment: Thanks you for your response.  Well appreciated.